# How to hide bootstrap dropdown inside a table when I hover over another row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a table inside which on each row I have options inside a dropdown.
When I click on the options, the dropdown opens (show class applied).
When I hover on other rows while the dropdown is open, it disappears (although the show class stays) and when I hover back on the existing row, it appears again.

I wish to do either of these 2 things:

1. The dropdown should not disappear even if I hover out of that particular row.
2. The dropdown should close once I hover out of the row.

I tried this code but failed:

```
$('#people-area-list tr').on('mouseleave', function () {
    var x = $(this).children('.action-btns .dropdown');
    x.removeClass('show');
});
```

HTML is:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" id="edit-submenu" data-toggle="dropdown">Options</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="edit-submenu">
        <a onclick="managePermission()" href="javascript:void(0);">Manage permissions</a>
        <a href="#">Reset password</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteModal(@userId,' @fullName ')">Delete User</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <tr class="leave">
     <td>...<td> 
     <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Options</a>
           <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="edit-submenu">
              <a onclick="managePermission()" href="javascript:void(0);">Manage permissions</a>
              <a href="#">Reset password</a>
              <a href="#" onclick="deleteModal(@userId,' @fullName ')">Delete User</a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".leave").on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).find(".dropdown").removeClass("show");
        $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("show");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried doing this. But for some reason it does not work.

Comment: Its work on me. Add that to your code and share pls

Comment: Mine is a bootstrap table using RazorView. The event is not getting triggered. I tried debugging it.

I won't be able to share the code.

Comment: My table was generated dynamically. So this didn't work.
I tweeked it a little to implement the event on document instead.

$(document).on({
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown').removeClass('show');
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
    }
}, "#table tr");

Comment: Try the last version. Probably you using asp.net. I don't know the language so i can't help more.